# fontspec Font not Found (AlegreyaSans package)

Tags: xetex, fontspec

This is a common problem, but none of the several links I've followed address my issue. An MWE:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
%\usepackage{Alegreya} % this works fine!

\begin{document}
Test!
\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... AlegreyaSansSC-\Alegreya@boldstyle 
                                                  }, ItalicFeatures = { Smal...
l.151       {AlegreyaSans}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... AlegreyaSansSC-\Alegreya@boldstyle 
                                                  Italic }, 
l.151       {AlegreyaSans}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Requested font "[AlegreyaSans-Regular.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/huerta/alegreya/AlegreyaSans-Regular.ttf
\g__fontspec_family_AlegreyaSans_int=\count124
Requested font "[AlegreyaSansSC-Regular.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/huerta/alegreya/AlegreyaSansSC-Regular.ttf
Requested font "[AlegreyaSans-Bold.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/huerta/alegreya/AlegreyaSans-Bold.ttf
Requested font "[AlegreyaSansSC-.ttf]/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> font not found, using "nullfont"

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "AlegreyaSansSC-" cannot be found.
```

What I don't understand is that, for instance, `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/huerta/alegreya/AlegreyaSans-Regular.ttf` **absolutely exists**! Is it possible that there is a permissions issue preventing this file from being accessed?

I'm using TeXlive 2016 on Fedora 24; I don't have this problem on a Mac with TeXlive 2015; is this a bug of some kind?

Comment: It's a bug in `AlegreyaSans.sty`; in some places `\Alegreya@boldstyle` is used instead of `\AlegreyaSans@boldstyle`.

Comment: Excellent; I should be able to adjust this myself. Should I report this in some way?

Comment: And you're welcome to add that as an answer if you like; I'll check it tonight and act accordingly.

Comment: I also added a temporary fix

Comment: The 2016/09/15 release of `AlegreyaSans` has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

The issue described below has been fixed in `AlegreyaSans.sty` released 2016/09/15.

### Original answer

It's a bug in `AlegreyaSans.sty`; in a few places the macro

```
\Alegreya@boldstyle
```

is used instead of `\AlegreyaSans@boldstyle`.

You should make a bug report; in the meantime, using the fact that the undefined control sequence is first used when `\setsansfont` is performed, you can work around the issue with the following trick:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%% Fix for the bug in AlegreyaSans
% make sure \setsansfont is defined
\usepackage{fontspec}
% start the fix by temporarily redefining
% \setsansfont to define the wrong macro
% to be the same as the right one
\makeatletter
% save a copy of \setsansfont
\let\fontspec@setsansfont\setsansfont
% redefine it to fix the issue and to redefine
% itself to the original one
\def\setsansfont{%
  \let\Alegreya@boldstyle\AlegreyaSans@boldstyle
  \let\setsansfont\fontspec@setsansfont
  \setsansfont
}
\makeatother
%%% end of fix, now load AlegreyaSans

\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}

\begin{document}
Test!
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're a rock star, egreg! Thanks; I'll get on that bug report tonight.