# "doi" text (not the doi itself) does not match document font

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

With TeX Live 2016 and compiling with Lua on Fedora 27, the following code produces the incorrect font for the "doi" text.

```
% LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%%% this fix is required to properly load my intended font
%%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329593/fontspec-font-not-found-alegreyasans-package
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\let\fontspec@setsansfont\setsansfont
\def\setsansfont{%
  \let\Alegreya@boldstyle\AlegreyaSans@boldstyle
  \let\setsansfont\fontspec@setsansfont
  \setsansfont
}
\makeatother
%%% end of fix

\usepackage[osf,sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@article{one,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {Title},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2000},
    volume          = {1},
    pages           = {2},
    doi            = {11.1111/abc.1111}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

How might I go about fixing this? All fixes I've found refer only to the font of the doi number itself, not the actual "doi" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about TeX Live 2016, but with TeX Live 2018 the `AlegreyaSans` package fails to set Alegreya Sans as the main font.

Adding a couple of fixes should solve the issue.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {Title},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2000},
    volume          = {1},
    pages           = {2},
    doi            = {11.1111/abc.1111}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%%% this fix is required to properly load my intended font
%%% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329593/fontspec-font-not-found-alegreyasans-package
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\let\fontspec@setsansfont\setsansfont
\def\setsansfont{%
  \let\Alegreya@boldstyle\AlegreyaSans@boldstyle
  \let\setsansfont\fontspec@setsansfont
  \setsansfont
}
\makeatother
%%% end of fix

\usepackage[osf,sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\urlstyle{same}

% Add these
\edef\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\edef\rmdefault{\sfdefault}
%%%

\begin{document}

Some text
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can avoid the package `AlegreyaSans`, though.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
    author          = {John Doe},
    title           = {Title},
    journaltitle    = {Journal},
    year            = {2000},
    volume          = {1},
    pages           = {2},
    doi            = {11.1111/abc.1111}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{AlegreyaSans}[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Numbers = OldStyle,
]

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

Upright 1234567890
\textit{Italic 1234567890}
\textbf{Bold 1234567890}
\textbf{\textit{BoldItalic 1234567890}}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this solves it for Tex Live 2016, as well. This font package sure has its fair share of bugs...